# Splitting Iterable in two Lists

Tags: java, list, collections, loops, iterable

I receive an Iterable from a method which contains two types of data.

1. Type A with the tag `"0"`
2. Type B with the tag `"1"`

So, I am able to detect which element belongs to which type and trying then to create an ArrayList for each and dump the respective data into it.

```
List<TextPair> valuesA = new ArrayList<TextPair>();
List<TextPair> valuesB = new ArrayList<TextPair>();
```

Here is how I try to do it:

```
for (TextPair value : values) {
    if(value.getSecond().toString().equals("0"))
        valuesA.add(value);
    else 
        valuesB.add(value);
}
```

The problem is that the first List seems to being overwritten with the values of the second. How can I tell this? Because when I look in the elements in both valuesA and valuesB they are identical and have both the values with the tag "1". I lose all the values with the tag "0". I don't know why this is happening and couldn't find a workaround yet.

My final goal is to compare every element of tag "0" with the elements of tag "1". I tried to do this without splitting the iterable, but since I can only traverse the iterable forward I could compare only the first element with "0" and lost the rest since I couldn't iterate back. Since the Iterable is provided from a framework (Hadoop) I have no chance to use another collection type than Iterable.
So, any ideas?

---

Now I'm adding a working code sample, but not tested with the Hadoop framework:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<TextPair> values = new ArrayList<TextPair>();
    values.add(new TextPair("cdr0", "0"));
    values.add(new TextPair("att0", "1"));
    values.add(new TextPair("cdr1", "0"));
    values.add(new TextPair("att1", "1"));
    values.add(new TextPair("cdr2", "0"));
    values.add(new TextPair("att2", "1"));

     List<TextPair> valuesA = new ArrayList<TextPair>();
     List<TextPair> valuesB = new ArrayList<TextPair>();

     for(TextPair value : values)
     {
         if(value.getSecond().toString().equals("0"))
             valuesA.add(value);
         else
             valuesB.add(value);
     }

     for(TextPair valueA : valuesA)
         System.out.println("valueA: " + valueA);

     for(TextPair valueB : valuesB)
         System.out.println("valueB: " + valueB);
}
```

I used an ArrayList for values though instead of an Iterable. Is there a way to fill an Iterable with elements? Or converting it to another Collection or other way around?

Comment: Print the `value.getSecond().toString()` if it is really in form "1" or "0". If there are any unnecessary white spaces just use `String.trim()` method.

Comment: @opi good eye :) The way it is right now it won't even compile.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with equals compare. I printed it out and all looks fine. Also when I leave out the else part, valuesA has the correct elements, i.e. elements of tag "0". As soon as I store the other elements in another List, the first one is overwritten.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with the if-else syntax. Eclipse doesn't give me any syntax-errors and the code compiles/runs successfully.

Comment: As the statement itself is correct, and the code looks valid too, the only way that the two lists can get messed up is by `TextPair`. Maybe `TextPair` isn't immutable and gets overwritten/modified elsewhere? (Just a guess because everything else seems to be Ok)

Comment: Could you try to make a minimal compilable example that reproduces your problem so that we could take a look at?

Comment: TextPair can't be immutable, since I have to set the values later. The fields are private though and can be set only throgh getter/setter methods. I've checked (by inserting a print.out in setter method) this and seen that it is not being called during splitting phase. It seems like that filling the second ArrayList is writing the same elements into the firs List as well.

Comment: I can't give you compilable code since you need Hadoop framework to run it and in order to reproduce the problem. I'm not expecting anyone to debug my code anyway. My question is rather how to iterate an Iterable many times so I can jump back to the beginning when I'm through with all elements. I have to compare the first element with the rest, and the second with the rest so on. Is there a way to do this with an Iterable?